# Terraform Azure provider - Azure Public access level for containers

Tags: azure, containers, terraform-provider-azure

I’m trying to change the container_access_type value from “private”, but I keep getting an error.

I'm able to do this action from the Azure UI. Something is probably missing in the Terraform code.

Please assist, thanks.

```
provider "azurerm" {
version = "=2.25.0"
features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage" {
  name     = "tfstorageresourcegroup"
  location = "North Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "account" {
  name = "${azurerm_resource_group.storage.name}"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.storage.location}"
  account_tier = "Standard"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.storage.name}"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  enable_https_traffic_only = true
  allow_blob_public_access = true
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
    name = "tftestcontainer"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.account.name}"
    container_access_type = "container"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blob" {
    name = "tftestblob"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.account.name}"
    storage_container_name = "${azurerm_storage_container.container.name}"
    type = "Page"
    size = "5120"
}
```

> Error: Error updating the Access Control for Container
> “tftestcontainer” (Storage Account “tfstorageresourcegroup” / Resource
> Group “tfstorageresourcegroup”): containers.Client#SetAccessControl:
> Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 – Original Error:
> autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=
> Code=“PublicAccessNotPermitted” Message=“Public access is not
> permitted on this storage
> account.\nRequestId:80d021ca-501e-009f-4aa6-86a404000000\nTime:2020-09-09T12:38:47.5769058Z”

Comment: The code is no problem, what is your Azure account permission?

Comment: I should be able to do anything in the account.

Comment: So what is the permission of your Azure account? Onwer？

Comment: member. Where can I look for my permissions in the account?

Comment: Find your Azure account in the Azure portal, see the role assignments.

Comment: Key Vault Administrator (preview), User Access Administrator, GEt Key, Owner, Key Vault Contributor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221252/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-omer-shliva).

Comment: I'm able to do this action from the Azure UI. Something is probably missing in the Terraform code.

Comment: Miss what? All the code works fine on my side by adding nothing.

Comment: I'm getting an error by running it using TF and it works through the Azure portal....

Comment: So which way do you use to authenticate for the Terraform? CLI or service principal?

Comment: I guess it's CLI since I did az login from powershell.

Comment: Then which account do you use to log in for the CLI? The same one you use in the portal?

Comment: The same one. I succeed in set-up the env after terraform destroy and apply it again.

Comment: Do you mean you solve the problem by adding the env variables?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while creating azure infra with terraform.

I editted for :

```
  container_access_type = "private"
```

inside:

```
    resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }
```

in the **main.tf** file.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the open [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2977).

So if you have [network_rules](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#example-usage-with-network-rules) in the storage account.

Take network rule depends on the container, meaning, create container first then apply the network rules.
Non-working Sample code:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "terraform_storage" {
  name = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  location = var.region
  account_tier = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
  account_kind = "Storage"

  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.publicsubnet.id]
  }
}

# Create container
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "filestore" {
  name                  = "filestore"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

Working Sample code:

```
# Storage account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                = local.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  account_kind             = var.storage_account_kind
  account_tier             = var.storage_account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.storage_account_replication_type

  enable_https_traffic_only = "true"

  tags = local.tags
}

# Create container
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "filestore" {
  name                  = "filestore"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

# SA Network rules
resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "netrules" {
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name

  default_action = "Deny"
  bypass = [
    "Metrics",
    "Logging",
    "AzureServices"
  ]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.filestore,
  ]
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24677)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this property on the storage account,
`allow_blob_public_access = true`

The documentation for the `azurerm` shows the required attribute to set,
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.82.0/docs/resources/storage_account#allow_blob_public_access

Note, I am using the azurerm provider `2.82.0`

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "images" {
  name                     = format("%simages", module.names.environment.storage_account.name_unique)
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  allow_blob_public_access = true
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  tags                     = azurerm_resource_group.default.tags
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "images" {
  name                  = "images"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.images.name
  container_access_type = "blob"
}
```